Access to the Cell values in each row of Datagridview
I write a foreach loop to access the value of all cells in each row of datagridveiw, but I have an Error

"DataGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no accessible extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

foreach (DataGridRow row in dataGrid_users.Rows)
{
    // Retrieve cell values from the row
    string name = row.Cells["name"].Valu?.ToString();
    string surname = row.Cells["surname"].Value?.ToString();
    string goal = row.Cells["goal"].Value?.ToString();
    string operation = row.Cells["operation"].Value?.ToString();
    string description = row.Cells["discription"].Value?.ToString();
    string job = row.Cells["job"].Value?.ToString();
    string station = row.Cells["station"].Value?.ToString();
    string date = row.Cells["date"].Value?.ToString();
}


Is it WinForms or WPF? Add tag.

It should be easier to grab the data from the backing classes you bound to the grid. If you didn't have used some sort of databinding consider it it makes life easier.

I think that the problem is that you wrote DataGridRow instead of DataGridViewRow in the foreach statement.
Let me know if it works.

Yes your are correct with it. I found it after asking question.
Thank you very much
